# Select position from a row and place in the same spot on the next sheet using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets in Excel. Sheet1 is called `Overview`, and Sheet2 is called `Comments`. I would like to go to the same row on the second sheet as the first, for example, if I had a cell selected in row 2 on Sheet1 and clicked the macro, it would take me to row 2 on the Sheet2.

My code so far (I placed a MsgBox just to see if was getting the the cell location):

```
Sub Comment()

Sheets("Overview").Select
myRow = ActiveCell.Row
myCol = ActiveCell.Column

MsgBox myRow & "," & myCol
Sheets("Comments").Select

(Stuck)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jumps to the same cell on the second sheet.

```
Sub Comment()
  Sheets("Overview").Select
  myRow = ActiveCell.Row
  myCol = ActiveCell.Column
  Sheets("Comments").Select
  Sheets("Comments").Cells(myRow,myCol).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
Sub jumpsheet()

Dim addr As String

addr = Selection.Address
Sheets("Comments").Activate
Range(addr).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

While this has been answered (and I gave +1 to Excellll) below is an alternative that works for any sheet position (sheet x goes to sheet x +1), and handles non range selections, hidden or non existent sheets. I use something very similar in a simple addin attached to a button on the toolbar, as well as code that steps backwards one sheet

```
Sub UpOneSheet()
On Error Resume Next
Application.Goto Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Range(ActiveCell.Address)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "You either " & vbNewLine & "a) have a chart or object selected or," & vbNewLine & _
"b) are  on the last sheet or, " & vbNewLine & "c) the sheet you are trying to access is hidden"
End Sub
```